# Отловить ошибку Asynchronous socket error 10061 Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как, при подключении клиента, если сервер не запущен, отловить системную ошибку и выдать сообщение о недоступности сервера? Перерыр гугл, но конструкция Try..Except не работает, как и Try..Except on E:Exception do. Или как проверить доступность сервера тогда? Код, который использовал, ниже: (событие об ошибке работает, но и системная ошибка также выдается, что логично)

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ScktComp;
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ClientSocket1: TClientSocket;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket;
      ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form1: TForm1;
implementation
{$R *.dfm}
//клик на кнопку
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Try
    ClientSocket1.Open;
  Except
    On E : Exception do Label1.Caption:='Ошибка подключения';
  End;
end;
//при ошибке
procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject;
 Socket:TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin Label1.Caption:='Ошибка';end;

end.
```

Comment: Вы скорее всего проверяли в отладочном режиме. Если запустить программу не с Delphi - ошибка будет перехвачена и выведено ваше сообщение

Comment: Прошу прощения, забыл упомянуть. Нет, запускал как в отладочном (тут вы верно сказали, что перехват будет), так и без него через ехешник, ошибка перехватилась, но и возникла системная ошибка windows

Comment: Я думаю вам может помочь данный [ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28789030/2546083)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не до конца довели код по обработке ошибок соединения.

Для того, чтобы подавить возбуждение исключения (если вы самостоятельно будете обрабатывать ошибку), в событии `OnErrorEvent` необходимо для ErrorCode присвоить 0.

В противном случае "внутренности" TCustomWinSocket будут считать, что ошибка не обработана и вызовут исключение `ESocketError`

Таким образом, итоговый код обработки события будет выглядеть так:

```
procedure TForm1.ClientSocket1Error(Sender: TObject; Socket:TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent;var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  Label1.Caption:='Ошибка ' + IntToStr(ErrorCode);
  ErrorCode:=0; // считаем, что ошибка обработана и подавляем исключение
  // обычно рекомендуется выполнить еще и Socket.Close, т.к. сокет уже явно не работоспособен.
end;
```

Comment: помогло, системная ошибка не возникает) Спасибо большое